# How many ip stacks are in use?

Tags: linux, networking

With the below command output:

```
~$ 
~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ff:ff:f9:f1:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
~$ 
~$ 
~$ 
~$ 
~$ 
~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ff:ff:f9:f1:06  brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.68.103/24 brd 192.168.68.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 5181sec preferred_lft 5181sec
    inet6 fe80::6fff:7fff:7ddd:3ddf/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
~$ 
~$ 
~$ 
~$ 
~$ 
~$ route -nNvee
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface    MSS   Window irtt
0.0.0.0         192.168.68.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0   0     0      0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0   0     0      0
192.168.68.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0   0     0      0
~$ 
~$ 
~$
```

---

1. Can I say that, there are two ipv4 stacks(Linux network subsystem) running? one for `eno1` interface and other for `wlp2s0` interface...
2. My understanding is, there is a routing table & eth interface per each network stack(ipv4 or ip6 or whatever).
   Does `lo` also have ipv4 stack(Linux network subsystem)? is yes, Why `route -nVee` doesn't show `lo` interface in the routing table?

Comment: Define "ipv* stack". Usually, it means the complete OS network system, so you have different ones per network namespace, but not different ones per interface.

Comment: @dirkt yes complete OS network system, as shown [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/net). OK different one per namespace. Need more clarity on loopback interface, as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1606857/how-does-loopback-interface-work-with-network-stack-in-a-host)

Answer (score 2):

There is one instance of the OS network data structures per network namespace. You could count this is one "stack". You could also count different network protocol stacks (like IPv4 and IPv6, or even older ones that are still supported by Linux) separately, then you'd have one each per network namespace.

All network interfaces in a network namespace belong to the same network stack (or several, if you count different protocols). There are various tables that either reference a particular interface (routing, firewall) or are per-interface (address assignment), but they still belong to the same kernel data structure instance.

The loopback interface is no different in this respect, though it plays a special role in the network stack (it's used whenever a transmission from a local address to a local address is involved, and it also offers a way to assign dedicated local IP addresses). So there is one loopback interface per network namespace (and hence network stack).

Answer (score 1):

First, the command you're running is showing information about the *link* - the physical interface (and that's why you see MAC addresses here) - the command `show ip addr` might be better.

There's probably only 2 IP stacks running in your example - 1 IPv4 stack and 1 IPv6 stack.

A convenient way to tell is to go by what `iptables` and `ip6tables` can see.

It's probably a good abstraction to say that everything running on a single IPv4 stack would be accessible through `iptables`, and everything running on a single IPv6 stack would be accessible through `ip6tables`.  This is likely true with the information you've provided.  All those interfaces--including `lo`--are being serviced by the same stack.

Probably the only way you can get anything like multiple independent stacks running for the same protocol is to use [network namespaces](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) or virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

The `eno1` interface doesn't have an IPv4 address, but the interface `wlp2s0` does.

The `lo` interface also has an IPv4 address.

All in all, there are two ipv4 stacks running.

Comment: When you say two ipv4 stacks, Does one ipv4 stack run for `lo` interface? Is it `socket(AF_UNIX,,,)` based?

Comment: `lo` is only for the local loopback at `127.0.0.1/8`, which certainly supports sockets.

Comment: `eno1`(wired ethernet - down) & `wlps20`(wireless ethernet - up) are two physical interfaces(layer 2). Why `route -nVee` doesn't show `lo` interface in the table? as updated in the query